# Visual Studio 2017 throws compilation error in TypeScript file using angular 2

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create an angular 2 app

Below is the typescript code

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ' < h1 > My First SharePoint Add In using Angular2... !!! < /h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

It is throwing the below errors

> cannot find module angular2/core
>
> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

For the second error I have also added

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

in the tsconfig.json

I have also installed [TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258) and restarted Visual studio, but no luck

I also tried `npm install -g typescript@latest`

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "imageslideshow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "slide show for image libraries",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.2",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.17",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "vignesh",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I try npm install I get the below message
[image]

Comment: Try to run 'npm install'

Comment: yes I tried `npm install -g typescript@latest`

Comment: Not npm install -g but just npm install in your solution or or a subdirectory of it where you have your packages

Comment: What does your `package.json` file look like?

Comment: @Saravana added it to the question now

Comment: @Vega I am actually trying to create a sharepoint add-in, so solution needs to be of that type!

Comment: try import line as 
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
The way Saravana mentioned

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have run `npm install` on your project and the
   dependencies are available in the `node_modules` folder.
2. In your package.json file you have dependencies with both Angular
       version 2 and 4. Decide which one you want to use.

If you want to use Angular version 4 your import should be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: tried npm install, but looks like there is some issue with it